# Python: Filter items 24 hour date format

Tags: python

Filtering some data items in range from `4/11 12:00 am` to `5/11 12:00 am`

Now, the *to* range exclude the items of that day since it only filter by **AM** which means `datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 5, 0, 0)`.

I want this to range should have 24 hour offset so that `5/11` ends the range at `6/11 12:00 am`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add 12 hours to all your data, do the filtering and substract 12 hours.

```
import datetime
original = datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 5, 0, 0)
added = original + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
```